# Using transient in Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I'm building an application using Play-Morphia and I'm trying to use transient on one of my fields in a class:

transient public List names;

The reason I do this is that I want to save the list of names in the MongoDB using Morphia, but not to serialize it when I retrieve my class.
On Morphia's website http://code.google.com/p/morphia/ you can see this example:

@Transient int notStored; //fields can be ignored (no load/save)
transient boolean stored = true; //not @Transient, will be ignored by Serialization/GWT for example.

This is specifically says that the "stored" field can be saved to the MongoDB but will be ignored by Serialization.

I tried to use it in my application, but in my case, "names" list didn't stored to the database.
Can anyone has an explanation for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PlayMorphia module automatically add @Transient annotation to transient. Please submit an issue report on https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-morphia/issues to request disable this feature.